# Project is buggy after upgrading Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, cocoa

I have an old app I maintaining. The app was first compiled on XCode 4.2. If I take the exact same project that works find and compile it on XCode 4.6 I'll get weird bugs such as ViewControllers not refreshing, Back doesn't work as it should etc'. If I'll take the same project and recompile it on xcode 4.2 on my other machine everything will work fine. Before I'm digging into the code, can someone give me an idea why something like this may happen? My main suspect is the Base SDK of each Xcode. Does that make sense?

Comment: I couldn't tell you if there will be a difference between 4.0 and 4.2, but historically the iOS frameworks *do* adapt slightly depending on what version of the SDK it was compiled against. You can't rule it out. And you should treat it as bugs in your app that the code paths hit by the older behaviour just mysteriously aren't hitting.

Comment: Is it possible to change the base SDK in XCode 4.6 back to IOS 5 instead of iOS 6.1 ? That would solve me a lot of problems

Comment: I strongly suspect you have a problem in your code (although some behaviours in iOS6 are new or operate differently i.e. auto-rotation / auto-layout).  Why not edit your question to include a sample error and the appropriate code? You'll have a much better chance of SO helping you.

Comment: No, it's an unsupported configuration. You should always use the latest SDK. And you wouldn't want to pretend these problems don't exist, anyway: The bugs are real, they were just hidden before.

Comment: @StevenFisher Please write your 2 comments it in a form of an answer so I can accept it. Thanks

Comment: Alright. I was rather hoping someone would be inspired by my comment and come up with a good, concrete answer. :)

Comment: Aside from the version numbers, this is a pretty general question. It may be a dupe, but I don't think it's too localized to be useful. I've removed the version numbers from the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't tell you if there will be a difference between 4.2 and 4.6, but historically the iOS frameworks on the device (and, to a lesser degree, the simulator) *do* adapt slightly depending on what version of the SDK an application was compiled against. You can't rule it out.

A classic (though now ancient) example is backgrounding. Apps built against older SDKs were quit when the Home button was pushed, rather than getting the newer behaviour. More recent (but subtle) examples have included several changes to table views and changes to device rotation.

You should *not* attempt to build with an older SDK using a newer compiler. Apple doesn't support that kind of configuration. You should always use the latest SDK. And you wouldn't want to pretend these problems don't exist, anyway: The bugs are real, they were just hidden before.

It's unlikely that you won't be able to fix those bugs in such a way that the older versions of iOS continue to function (though you may discover it opens a can of worms that you decide isn't worth fixing for older OSes).